# insert information to external DB in android studio

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm using android studio to get information from user and insert it into external DB, and i saw a lot of videos in youtube but still there is a problem when run it says: "registration success" but doesn't insert into DB

This is my code in android studio

public class signup extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText email,password,name;
Switch visually_impaired;
String Email,Password,Name,Visually_impaired,Beacon_alert,Buildings_alert;;
Context ctx = this;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_editText);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password_editText);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_editText);
    visually_impaired = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.blindOpt);

}

public void register(View v){
    Email = email.getText().toString();
    Name = name.getText().toString();
    Password = password.getText().toString();
    Visually_impaired = visually_impaired.getText().toString();
    BackGround b = new BackGround(this);
    b.execute(Email,Password,Name,Visually_impaired);
}

class BackGround extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

    Context ctx;
    public BackGround(Context ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        String email = strings[0];
        String password = strings[1];
        String name = strings[2];
        String visually_impaired = strings[3];

        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://ksuexpress.com/register.php");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("email","UTF-8")+ " = "+URLEncoder.encode(email,"UTF-8") +"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+ " = "+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8") +"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("name","UTF-8")+ " = "+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8") +"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("visually_impaired","UTF-8")+ " = "+URLEncoder.encode(visually_impaired,"UTF-8");
            bufferWriter.write(data);
            bufferWriter.flush();
            bufferWriter.close();
            os.close();
            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            is.close();
            return "Registration success....";

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Toast.makeText(ctx,result,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

}

and also i have a php code in server that uses POST and insert it to the DB

can anyone help me please ...

Comment: check this project on github, it does exactly what you are looking for https://github.com/AnanthaRajuCprojects/Android-HTTP-Post

Answer (score 0):

Some possible fixes:

1. change `" = "` to `"="` without spaces
2. add some logs in `doInBackground` and make sure you're getting the correct parameters into email,password,etc.
3. change `InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream(); is.close();` to `httpURLConnection.connect();`

Comment: it's return the correct parameters, and i change = without space but doesn't work

Comment: see my new 3rd suggestion